# Writing arithmetic code in Java

Tags: java, math

I have the below one line of code:

```
variableDoubleValue = ((10*variableDoubleA) + (6.25*variableDoubleB) – (5*variableByteC) + 5);
```

How can I write it in a Java understandable code?

Comment: I can understand that.

Comment: Well, if `variableDoubleValue`, `variableDoubleA`, etc. are defined, then that should compile fine (though the variable names should describe what they mean).

Comment: I would start by giving the variables some meaningful names.

Comment: I hope you're aware that you can't just write a single line of Java.  You'll need variable declarations and initialization, and those must be contained within a method in a class.  Also, based on your comment below about confusion between character \8211 and dashes, I can't help but wonder whether you're trying to write this in a word processor rather than an IDE or text editor.

Answer (score 1):

From what I infer from your question, you want a Java-language based variable declaration and assignment.

Well, if this is the case, then the result will be :-

```
 //public class MathemathicalExpression{
 // public static void main(String[] args){
 //  Double A=some_value,B=some_value,Value=0;  considering A,B and Value to be of type Double
 //  Byte C=some_value;    considering C to be of type Byte.
     Value = 10 * A + 6.25 * B - 5 * C + 5;
 // }
 //}
```

Comment: You understood my question well but still it is giving me the error:

illegal character: \8211

What does that mean please?

Comment: It was the dash :).  I removed it a replaced it with a "real" dashed and it recognized it as a minus.

Comment: I'd suggest embedding this in a method so it's at least somewhat self-contained.

Comment: @pjs-Ok,now I've done it for better presentation as advised by you. THANKS.